# xCode 6 "Storyboard doesn't contain a view controller with identifier" when deploying back to iOS7 device

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, ios8, xcode6, ios7.1

I have a deployment target iOS 7.1 app compiled with xCode 5.1 deployed to a device.

**Upon updating to xCode 6**, I did some upgrades to the app, and added a view controller to the storyboard with a certain identifier. I verified that the controller exists, the identifier is valid, and everything is working fine when deployed to an iOS8 device.

However, when deploying back to iOS7.1 device, overwriting existing app, I get  **"Storyboard  doesn't contain a view controller with identifier"** exception bad access when trying to create an instance of the view controller. I tried clean>build, I tried killing the app, but still get the exception **when running from xCode6**

If I add an exception handler, the app works, but the new view controller is not instantiated. Deleting the app on device and reinstalling fixes the issue, although there are orientation issues. Unfortunately deleting the app is not always the case when existing clients in the field are using the old app version.

**How can I make sure that my new storyboard controllers are properly working on iOS 7.1 devices with existing installations?**

```
    @try {
        if(__privacyScreen == nil)
        {
            __privacyScreen = [kMainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"privacyScreen"];

        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
//this will cause exception when overwriting an iOS7.1 installation
        DLog(@"Exception: %@",[exception description]);

    }
    @finally {

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried a clean in Xcode?

Comment: Yes, I tried clean. Just confirmed that the old app install on iOS7 does not see another new text field added in xCode6. I venture to guess that the storyboards are not compatible, and the old one is being used by the 7.1 app. The old storyboard from previous install does not have new elements added in xCode6.

Comment: I am stuck on the same issue as we speak. Xcode 6.1 doesn't seem to allow viewcontroller identifiers (or I can't find), which sounds silly, unless there is a substitute.

Comment: I had similar symptoms, and it turned out that the problem was that I was trying to load a UISplitViewController on iPhone running iOS 7. UISplitViewController for iPhone was introduced in the iOS 8 SDK, and only works on iOS 7 as the root view controller.